# How can I show 2 columns in a combobox? (multiple values)

Tags: c#, combobox

Right now I have this:

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM LOGIN WHERE RECHTEN=2", conn);
dtt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dtt);
for (int i = 0; i < dtt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    txtKlantid.Items.Add(dtt.Rows[i]["klantId"]);
}
```

Now it only shows the `klantId`, but I also want to show the name. And when I've that, so the `klantId` and the name how can I only select the `klantId` when I say:

```
selectedUserId = combobox.Text;
```

EDIT:

//THIS IS WHERE I INITIALISE THE COMBOBOX

```
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT (kg.voornaam+' '+kg.achternaam + ' - ' + CONVERT(varchar,l.klantId)) AS dispValue FROM LOGIN l inner join klantGegevens kg on l.klantId=kg.klantid WHERE RECHTEN=2", conn);
        dtt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dtt);
        txtKlantid.DisplayMember = "dispValue";
        txtKlantid.ValueMember = "klantId";
        txtKlantid.DataSource = dtt;
```

//THIS IS THE BUTTON FOR DELETING A USER

```
  private void btnDeleteUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (userInformation.addPersonsPermission)
            {
                int selectedUserId = Convert.ToInt32(((DataRowView)txtKlantid.SelectedValue)["klantId"]);
                if (users.deleteKlantAdmin(selectedUserId))
                {
                    MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Gebruiker "+selectedUserId+" is verwijderd", "Verwijderd");
                }
                else
                {
                    MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Er ging iets fout, contacteer de beheerder", "Fout");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                loginAddUser addUserLogin = new loginAddUser();
                addUserLogin.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do u mean 2 columns?

Comment: @Jenssen if you fetch the values from the db table and assign it as a datasource, then `txtKlantid.SelectedValue` is smart enough to say which `klantId` is currently selected

Comment: @Jenssen you have not selected `l.klantId` in the query

Comment: Change the query into `SELECT (kg.voornaam+' '+kg.achternaam + ' - ' + CONVERT(varchar,l.klantId)) AS dispValue, l.klantId AS klantId FROM LOGIN l inner join klantGegevens kg on l.klantId=kg.klantid WHERE RECHTEN=2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties will be your friends in this case.

Please avoid selecting all the fields from the table just to fill your combobox. You can just do something like,

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT (name + ' - ' + CONVERT(varchar,klantId)) AS dispValue, klantId FROM LOGIN WHERE RECHTEN=2", conn);
dtt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dtt);
txtKlantid.DisplayMember = "dispValue";
txtKlantid.ValueMember = "klantId";
txtKlantid.DataSource = dtt;
```

In this example, `txtKlantid.SelectedValue` will give you the `klantId` values and `txtKlantid.Text` will give you the `name - klantId` values.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Great! But unfortunately it gives me the error in sql: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'desc'."

Comment: Yes, works but now sql says: "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'test - ' to data type int."

Comment: yes this one works. So now If I want to select the klantId I've to say " selectedUserId = txtKlantid.SelectedValue;" but if I do that it says "Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: Sorry for all those questions/errors but now it says: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.IConvertible'."

Comment: `int selectedUserId = Convert.ToInt32(((DataRowView)txtKlantid.SelectedValue)["klantId"]);`

Comment: Yes, Also found that one but that also doesn't work. It is telling me:klantId is neither a DataColumn nor a DataRelation for table .

Comment: I'm using windows application.

Comment: Please see my edit. That's how It's currently. I've set the DisplayMember and the Valuemember.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DisplayMember` and    `ValueMember` property of ComboBox

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM LOGIN WHERE RECHTEN=2", conn);
dtt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dtt);

txtKlantid.DisplayMember = "Name"; //Name of field to display
txtKlantid.ValueMember = "klantId";
txtKlantid.DataSource = dtt;
```

And you can get `Name` And `Id` back by following

```
var name = txtKlantid.Text;
var id = txtKlantid.SelectedValue;
```

As per your requirement you can combine Id and Name

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    txtKlantid.Items.Add(dtt.Rows[i]["klantId"].ToString()+"-"+dtt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks works great, but now I still don't see them beside each other. For example how can I get: "name-Klantid". Now I only see:"name". Thankss!!

Comment: yesyes, it workss. One more question, what's the proper way to see what klantId has been selected? (not the name but klantId)